# PHP - AB Test Fails

Tags: php, apache

My web app is php native, no frameworks or anything, my server is 32GB ram, when there is huge traffic on the website, it comes too slow (2 sec page loading becomes 50 Seconds).

Tried AB Test using

```
ab -n 20000 -c 1000  mywebsite.com
```

It gives

```
apr_socket_connect(): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

after some time

Is there anyway to allocate more RAM to php or something else ?

Comment: ... or review code. Hard to imagine analyse without

Comment: Are you running PHP as FCGI or as an Apache Module?

Comment: @MiSAKACHi no it's FPM Application by apache

Comment: So FCGI then. Are you on Linux or Windows?

Comment: Just because your app is frameworkless it doesn't mean it does not eat lots of memory. What's the average memory footprint of such request you mentioned? There are number of factors to consider and without any this is just reading tea leaves.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, you are hitting the maximum concurrent connections. Read the following suggestions below:

> **For Windows Server (MPM_WinNT)**

- Configure the `ThreadLimit` and `ThreadsPerChild` on `httpd-mpm.conf`. The value should be enough to handle multiple and/or concurrent requests.

> **For Linux (Module Dependent)**

- Depending on the module you are using, set the `MaxRequestWorkers` directive to the number of connections you want to handle.

For additional reference, you can check this documentation for the directives that are needed to be configured so that your server can properly handle multiple and/or concurrent requests. [Apache MPM Modules](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html)

Comment: I'm on CentOs 7

Comment: You mean mpm_event? Don't change it. Do some tests with the `MaxRequestWorkers` directive first.

Comment: How to change directives for EVENT ? i only know how to do it for workers

Comment: the same method on how you change for worker. Just key in `MaxRequestWorkers xxx` since both of them understands this directive then restart apache. :)